# Xpath grab div contents based on span class

Tags: xpath

```
<div class="accrd-row">
<h3 class="ui-helper-reset ui-accordion-header ui-corner-top ui-accordion-header-collapsed ui-corner-all ui-state-default ui-accordion-icons" role="tab" id="ui-id-1" aria-controls="ui-id-2" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0"><span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"></span><span class="icon icon-ki-act-panda"></span><a href="#">Outdoor Activities</a></h3>

<div class="accrd-detail ui-accordion-content ui-corner-bottom ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content" id="ui-id-2" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">Need to grab this text here</div>

</div>
```

I am trying to grab the text:

```
Need to grab this text here
```

Based on that the span above has the word "panda" in it. I know it is something like:

```
//span/@class[contains(.,'panda')]/following-sibling::a/div
```

But I cannot seem to get this to pick up the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to go back to the parent of span since the div you are looking for is a sibling of h3 not span.

There is probably a nicer way to do it but this is working for me to get the div element you need:

```
//h3//span[contains(@class, 'panda')]/parent::h3/following-sibling::div
```